# How to make ReIn with Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)?

Tags: ros, object-recognition, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

the Recognition Infrastructure does not compile with Maverick (see its ROS_BUILD_BLACKLIST file).
The problem is that soci.h is (strangely) not found by cmake.
Is there any action going on to solve this issue at the moment?

I see some people are actively using some of the packages contained in the object_recognition stack. Could they explain how to do so using maverick?

I feel I am asking something stupid here, but I really can't figure out how to solve that cmake problem and use this stack. Any hint is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Raph

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9251/how-to-make-rein-with-ubuntu-10.10-(maverick)?/) by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1382 on 2011-03-01

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to the help from Ruben, he was able to build a patch for this problem:

[ticket 5069](http://code.ros.org/trac/wg-ros-pkg/ticket/5069)

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) on 2011-03-28**:
thanks guys!

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-03-23**:
Notice: a new patch (version 2) was submitted to be more 'clean'